# Difference between HttpContext.Request and Request

Tags: .net, asp.net

What is the difference between the three ASP.NET objects:

- HttpContext.Current.Request
- HttpContext.Request
- Request

Are these exactly the same?

## Edit 1

Do these objects behave differently inside `global.asax`/`global.asax.vb` and `default.aspx`/`default.aspx.vb`.

## Edit 2

OK I'll try to be specific this time. Which of the following should I use:

```vb
' File: global.asax
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
    'If HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
    'If HttpContext.Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
        'do something
    End If
End Sub

' File: default.aspx
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
    'If HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
    'If HttpContext.Request.Url.Port = 80 Then
        'do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check if they are all equal! HttpContext.Current is accessible when you code in Global.asax.cs but others are not available.

Comment: @Jani: I do want to know how these three behave inside `global.asax`, `global.asax.vb`, `default.aspx` and `default.aspx.vb`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well:

- [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) is a *static* property returning the current `HttpContext` for the thread
- [`HttpContext.Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request.aspx) is an *instance* property returning the `HttpRequest` for the `HttpContext` you call it on
- [`Page.Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) is an instance property in `Page`, returning the `Request` associated with the page you call it on (typically implicitly `this`)

So `HttpContext.Current.Request` will use both of the first two properties in order to get the request associated with the current thread. If you're in the thread dealing with a request, that's going to be the same as the `Page.Request` within the relevant page which is being rendered.

However, if your rendering kicks off a *different* thread, the code running in the other thread can still get at the `Request` via `Page.Request` (because it's just a normal property) but there'll be no `HttpContext` associated with the thread - so `HttpContext.Current.Request` wouldn't work.

EDIT: To respond to the edited question, in global.asax the `Request` property refers to [`HttpApplication.Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.request.aspx), and is probably the best approach to use. `HttpContext.Request` won't work, because that's trying to access a static property as if it were an instance property. `HttpContext.Current.Request` *should* work, assuming the context has been associated with the thread by that point.

Comment: +1 - This was helpful. Just curious why `.Request` does not show up in Visual Studio as a Property of `HttpContext`. (e.g. If you create an instance of `HttpContext`, intellesense will not show you `Request` as a property.)

Comment: @Joel: No idea... it should do, I would expect. Does the same code compile when you just type it in manually?

Comment: @Jon: I'v eedited my question. Please look into it, thanks. @Joel: same problem with intellisense.

Comment: @Jon - No. (I think you responded to a "bad" version of my comment that  I accidentally submitted it before it was done. See edit.)  Doesn't show on instances of `HttpContext` either. e.g., `HttpContext x = null;`  VS should treat `x` as an instance of `HttpContext` as far as intellesense is concerned. Also, does not list `Request` in the object browser either.

Comment: @Jon - I can generalise this and make it into a separate question. I have come accross this kind of thing before.

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same. There are simply various shortcuts built-into classes you're inheriting from such as Controller and Page.

Comment: Clarity: Request is a direct pointer to HttpContext.Request. HttpContext is pointing to ControllerContext.HttpContext which in "normal" cases is HttpContext.Current.Request. Mock testing is the only case I can think of where they *might* be different.