# Accessing DOM from application_error

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-error

I have a custom error handler for an asp.net site.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    //if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductionMode"] == "Yes")
    #if (!DEBUG)
    Server.Transfer("~\\GlobalExceptionHandler.aspx");
    #endif
}
```

It works fine and dandy when retrieving exception information cause it'll just snag `Server.getLastException()` and email it on to me for review

However, I have some TextBoxes on the page and I'd like to send the value of those textboxes along with the email.  Maybe it's not quite the DOM I'm looking for access to but instead those posted variables.

I tried looking at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` but it showed no keys.

So Does anyone know how to access the formvalues when globally catching an exception?

Answer (score 2):

### Accessing the Form Values

To access the form values in `Global.Application_Error`, you can simply use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.

Here is a proof of concept, where a page immediately throws an exception on post(back) to hit the application error handler:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint on the assignment to `test`, then stepping over it (with <kbd>F10</kbd>) when it is hit, you can see that `test` is indeed set to the post(back)'s form-values collection.

### Accessing the Postback Control Values

Alternatively, you can access the postback control values by adding them to the session on postback, for example...

```
// ************code behind
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["TextBox1"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

..., and accessing the session in the application error handler - for instance:

```
// ************Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Use Session["TextBox1"].
}
```

A [CodeVerge thread](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.state-management/how-to-use-textbox.text-in-global-as/308654) speaks to approach well - particularly Benson Yu's reply.

Comment: As stated, I already tried using the Request variable but Form is going up empty.  I tried saving the form in the Session (I parsed all the keys/values into a string) Varible but when I tried accessing Session it threw an HTTP Exception

Comment: @Cheruvian: There is [room to screw up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5548039/1810429) checking the request's form-values collection in `Global.asax.cs`: so double check that you are, in fact, doing it correctly.  Having said this, be sure to edit your question to explain how you have tried adding the control values to the session and using the session in `Application_Error` and *the exception that resulted*.  These details significantly affect the question(s) you are asking: so it is important that your question include them.