# HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[somekeyvalue] always returns null

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, httpcontext

I am using SSO authentication for my application.
I am receiving response for authentication via SAML.

In chrome i can see the Saml response in SAMLResponse KEY as post data.

But the value always returns NULL.

Even Keys.count is zero.

Please help me out for getting the value for HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]

Comment: Don't parse SAML yourself. Use an existing library. Properly validating SAML2 messages is hard and most simple implementations contains severe vulnerabilities.

Comment: i didnt parse SAML..Actually some other team is mapping this and send saml file..From their end they are sending SAML (They showed me using saml extension in the developer tool.)...But in my application it receives as empty value. Strange fact is the code works fine in DEV...But it returns empty value in QA...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Page.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]
```

I seem to recall having issues with this in the past.

Here is a link to a thread on the difference in HttpContext.Request vs. Page.Request:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5548039/795047